# Зачем делают проверку на xhr запрос

Tags: node.js, xhr

Привет! Учу NodeJS, вроде всё получается. Довольно часто встречаю такую вот проверку:

```
if(req.xhr){
  res.send(event);
} else {
  res.render('events/details',{event:event});
}
```

Зачем её делают люди, что она даёт и как применяется?

upd. Вот я смотрю drywall , там в примерах так и сказано, если хотите всё правильно использовать - берите за основу страницы админки и их запросы. Но там на банальный get запрос пристутствует эта проверка xhr. Например, я хочу получить список пользователей с Ником на А. Пишу код, ставлю фильтр, а потом, в конце кода рекомендуют поставить эту проверку. Смысл что она делает я понимаю. А для чего это делается, если я на этой странице xhr никак не задействую?

Comment: Вот я смотрю [drywall](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall/wiki) , там в примерах так и сказано, если хотите всё правильно использовать - берите за основу страницы админки и их запросы. Но там на банальный get запрос пристутствует эта проверка xhr. Например, я хочу получить список пользователей с Ником на А. Пишу код, ставлю фильтр, а потом, в конце кода рекомендуют поставить эту проверку. Смысл что она делает я понимаю. А для чего это делается, если я на этой странице xhr никак не задействую?

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: Это программисты, не добравшиеся до content-negotiation. Различный вывод ответа в зависимости от типа запроса, только, конечно, нужно смотреть заголовок Accept запроса и в зависимости от этого менять тип вывода.

Answer (score 0):

Если приходит XHR, то этот код просо возвращает "голые" данные. В противном случае возвращает отрендренную страницу с данными.

Делаю это для удобства - один и тот же URL возвращает ответ в разном формате.

Comment: Это понятно. А как может быть XHR на обычной странице, если я это не планирую реализовывать в функционале сайта? Может быть это как-то связано с живыми обновлениями страниц? просто не понимаю в каждой странице drywall так реализовано, а какой профит от такого подхода

Comment: @NikitaM я не понимаю о чем вы спрашиваете. Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.